# this is my webapi.xml file please give me solution this url not working for Get Api Call <HOST url>/rest/V1/wishlist/customer?customerId=7

Tags: magento2

```
<route url="/V1/wishlist/customer/items" method="GET">
    <service class="Xteam\Wishlist\Api\WishlistManagementInterface" method="getWishlistItemsByCustomerId"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous" />
    </resources>
    <data>
        <parameter name="customerId" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
    </data>
</route>
<route url="/V1/wishlist/customer/item/:customerId/:productId" method="DELETE">
    <service class="Xteam\Wishlist\Api\WishlistManagementInterface" method="removeProductFromWishlist"/>
   <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous" />
    </resources>      
</route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

Method **GET**

**URL** : `https://yourwebsite.com/rest/V1/wishlist/customer/items?customerId=12`

12 is a customer id

https://yourwebsite.com/ is a domain name change it

Method **DELETE**

URL : `https://yourwebsite.com/rest/V1/wishlist/customer/item/?customerId=12/?productId=101`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. and i have fix the issue actually problem is my module not enable . I ran all commands but forgot s:up